# How do I enlarge outliner font?

Tags: outliner, font

Please let me know how to enlarge outliner font, Icon display. + and - bottom does NOT work on outliner.

Answer (score 7):

You can change your UI font size, and then use <kbd>Numpad -</kbd> where you want smaller font.

*Preferences > Themes> Text Style > Widget*

[image]